# Unable to vertically align correctly long table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, arrays, makecell

I am using the package **longtable** and what I want to achieve is to have **vertically centered cells**, and **equal row height**.

I have tried using *m{}* column type, to achieve the vertical centering, but when I try to increase row height using *arraystretch*, the vertical alignmnent fails. So I need help in two matters

1. Why does arraystretch mess with the vertical alignment? How else could the functionality of arraystretch be achieved and keep the alignment?
2. *Arraystretch* does not give me equal row height but it only increases padding. How can I have equal row height?

Here is the output, you can see the difference in the arrow lengths:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}%table colors
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\myhline}{\hline\hline\hline}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{footnotesize} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
  \rowcolors{2}{MidnightBlue!10}{white}
  \begin{longtable}{ | C{1.7in} | C{1.5in} | C{0.65in} | C{0.6in} | C{0.6in} | }
 \hline
\rowcolor{MidnightBlue!30}
\textbf{test1} & \textbf{test2} &  \textbf{test3} & \textbf{test4} & \textbf{test5} \\
  \myhline
  \textbf{qwerty} &  testing simple & - & + & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty2} & testing simple long test & - & + & -\\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing simple long test & - & + & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing simple long test & - & + & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing simple long test & - &+ & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing reaaaaaaaaaaaally simple loooooooooooooong test & - & + & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing simple long test & - & + & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing simple long test (pixels) & - & + & + \\
  \textbf{qwerty} & testing simple long test & - & + & + \\
  \hline
 \rowcolor{white} 
 \caption{Table testing} 
\label{my_label}
 \end{longtable}

\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will you add more rows to your table later? Is `longtable` or a different package, that can break tables across pages mandatory?

Comment: Yes, I will. It is only for the the example that I didn't include all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Using `cellspace` (instead using of `arraystretch`)and `xltabular` (instead of `longtable`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}%table colors 
\usepackage{array, makecell, tabularx, xltabular}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
    \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{C}
%
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
 \centering
 \setlength\columnsep{4pt}
 \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
 \rowcolors{2}{MidnightBlue!10}{white}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |>{\bfseries}O{C{1.75}}|O{C{1.75}}|
                                               O{C{0.50}}|O{C{0.50}}|O{C{0.50}}| }
     \Xhline{1pt}
test 1  & \textbf{test 2}   
            & \textbf{test 3}   & \textbf{test 4}   & \textbf{test 5}   \\     
     \Xhline{0.5pt}
qwerty  & testing simple            & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing simple long test  & - & + & -\\
qwerty  & testing simple long test  & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing simple long test  & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing simple long test  & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing reaaaaaaaaaaaally simple loooooooooooooong test 
                                    & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing simple long test  & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing simple long test (pixels) 
                                    & - & + & + \\
qwerty  & testing simple long test  & - & + & + \\
     \Xhline{1pt}
    \end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Table testing}
\label{my_label}
}

\end{document}
```